# Hadoop copy file to remote server

Tags: hadoop

[image]

How do i achive this : initiate a hadoop command from the server with Hadoop client installed to move the data from Hadoop cluster to a remote linux server which do not have hadoop client installed ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't send all blocks of a file to a remote host, you would have to do this

```
hadoop fs -get /path/src/file 
scp ./file user@host:/path/dest/file
```